# how to declare method in 'vuejs' as for 'Handlebars.registerHelper'?

Tags: methods, handlebars.js, vue.js, handlebarshelper

I'm going from "Handlebarjs" to "Vuejs".
I want to declare a method that is invoked in several parts of my code.

As for Handlebars.registerHelper ();

please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can prototype your components before initializing your app

```
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

new Vue(...)
```

axios will be available in every component you declare

```
...
methods: {
    getSomething: function() {
       this.$http.get('blablabla', ...
...
```

You can register your functions as well

Comment: I already read the data with jQuery.   
I just need to implement the method of 'vuejs' and it can be used in different parts